# JSON SerDe JAR not getting detected while creating a Table in Hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hadoop2, hive-serde

Can anyone please tell a proper solution for the below error scenario.

Below mentioned details are my Hadoop and its ecosystem versions

```
Hadoop Version: 2.7.1
Hive Version: 1.2.2
```

I was trying to install and configure JSON SerDe into my hive's library path. And, the steps which I followed were mentioned below

```
Step 1: Installed & Moved SerDe into Hive's Library path
Step 2: Added the Jar through hive Shell, modified the hive-site.xml's 
        property name hive.aux.jars.path. 
Step 3: Verified it by executing the list jars command in hive also. But 
        while invoking the json serde, error is being thrown.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Important Note:** I added an entry in maven too, gave 777 permission for the jar file in linux. Additionally, I added the jar both in hdfs and local filesystem. But, still the error is being thrown

Name of the JSON SerDe jar which I used was: `json-serde-1.3.7.3.jar`

Row format SerDe: `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe`

Comment: The jsonserde jar is detected, the exception is coming due to a different problem.

Comment: Can you pls tell a solution for it franklinsijo like why it's coming

Comment: There isn't enough information to proceed. Can you restart your hive shell `hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console` with debug mode, and post what it throws when the DDL is run.

Comment: franklinsijo, I have attached a new screenshot with this page by opening hive shell in the DEBUG mode which you have mentioned. So, can you please let me know about the issue now

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon, it is actually `NoClassDefFoundException`.